# Radiobuttons with alertDialog

Tags: android

I have a problem with my radiobuttons because it's showing the radio group in myLayout instead of in the alertDialog, I was trying to do it but I can't figure out how to put it because I'm totally new in android.

```
   View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radiogroup, null);
    setContentView(myView);
    RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)
    myView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    int radioGroupId = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton myCheckedButton = (RadioButton)
    myView.findViewById(radioGroupId);
    int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(myCheckedButton);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)   
    .setMessage("Choose Startup Color:")
    .setPositiveButton("Set Startup Color", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        }
     })

    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        }
     })

    .show();
```

Comment: You forgot to post your code. If you can post your code, we might be able to help you.

Comment: I was adding whole the details :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the layout of your activity to show the RadioGroup layout by doing

```
View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radiogroup, null);
setContentView(myView);
```

If you want to show that View inside your AlertDialog you can set it by calling `setView` on your builder and passing `myView` as a parameter.